# Can't install dev-util/meson-0.49.2::gentoo, with emerge, can't install any other package from the list

Tags: software-installation, gentoo, emerge

I am installing gentoo and now I am installing the packages with:

```
(chroot)ubuntu /boot # emerge --ask --newuse --deep --verbose sys-boot/grub:2 os-       prober
```

and dev-util/meson-0.49.2::gentoo fails, with this error message:

```
 Messages for package dev-util/meson-0.49.2:

 * ERROR: dev-util/meson-0.49.2::gentoo failed (compile phase):
 *   (no error message)
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line  124:  Called src_compile
 *   environment, line 2627:  Called distutils-r1_src_compile
 *   environment, line  819:  Called _distutils-r1_run_foreach_impl 'distutils-r1_python_compile'
 *   environment, line  322:  Called python_foreach_impl 'distutils-r1_run_phase' 'distutils-r1_python_compile'
 *   environment, line 2161:  Called multibuild_foreach_variant '_python_multibuild_wrapper' 'distutils-r1_run_phase' 'distutils-r1_python_compile'
 *   environment, line 1533:  Called _multibuild_run '_python_multibuild_wrapper' 'distutils-r1_run_phase' 'distutils-r1_python_compile'
 *   environment, line 1531:  Called _python_multibuild_wrapper 'distutils-r1_run_phase' 'distutils-r1_python_compile'
 *   environment, line  537:  Called distutils-r1_run_phase 'distutils-r1_python_compile'
 *   environment, line  810:  Called distutils-r1_python_compile
 *   environment, line  680:  Called esetup.py 'build'
 *   environment, line 1078:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *       "${@}" || die "${die_args[@]}";
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-util/meson-0.49.2::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-util/meson-0.49.2::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/meson-0.49.2/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/meson-0.49.2/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/meson-0.49.2/work/meson-0.49.2'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/dev-util/meson-0.49.2/work/meson-0.49.2
```

so I can't install 4 other packages, which are required to install grub. The output of emerge --info '=dev-util/meson-0.40.2':

```
Portage 2.3.62 (python 3.6.5-final-0, default/linux/amd64/17.0, gcc-8.2.0, glibc-2.28-r6, 4.18.0-15-generic x86_64)
=================================================================
                         System Settings
=================================================================
System uname: Linux-4.18.0-15-generic-x86_64-AMD_A10-9700_RADEON_R7,_10_COMPUTE_CORES_4C+6G-with-gentoo-2.6
KiB Mem:     7923700 total,   3017028 free
KiB Swap:    1048572 total,   1048572 free
Timestamp of repository gentoo: Sun, 21 Apr 2019 00:45:01 +0000
Head commit of repository gentoo: a8e55f42cc0cb07092ed0b0d400755a4db8a1a86
sh bash 4.4_p23-r1
ld GNU ld (Gentoo 2.31.1 p5) 2.31.1
app-shells/bash:          4.4_p23-r1::gentoo
dev-lang/perl:            5.26.2::gentoo
dev-lang/python:          2.7.15::gentoo, 3.6.5::gentoo
sys-apps/baselayout:      2.6-r1::gentoo
sys-apps/openrc:          0.38.3-r1::gentoo
sys-apps/sandbox:         2.13::gentoo
sys-devel/autoconf:       2.69-r4::gentoo
sys-devel/automake:       1.16.1-r1::gentoo
sys-devel/binutils:       2.31.1-r4::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc:            8.2.0-r6::gentoo
sys-devel/gcc-config:     2.0::gentoo
sys-devel/libtool:        2.4.6-r3::gentoo
sys-devel/make:           4.2.1-r4::gentoo
sys-kernel/linux-headers: 4.14-r1::gentoo (virtual/os-headers)
sys-libs/glibc:           2.28-r6::gentoo
Repositories:

gentoo
    location: /usr/portage
    sync-type: rsync
    sync-uri: rsync://rsync.gentoo.org/gentoo-portage
    priority: -1000
    sync-rsync-verify-jobs: 1
    sync-rsync-verify-metamanifest: yes
    sync-rsync-extra-opts: 
    sync-rsync-verify-max-age: 24

ACCEPT_KEYWORDS="amd64"
ACCEPT_LICENSE="* -@EULA"
CBUILD="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
CHOST="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
CONFIG_PROTECT="/etc /usr/share/gnupg/qualified.txt"
CONFIG_PROTECT_MASK="/etc/ca-certificates.conf /etc/env.d /etc/gconf /etc/gentoo-release /etc/revdep-rebuild /etc/sandbox.d /etc/terminfo"
CXXFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
DISTDIR="/usr/portage/distfiles"
EMERGE_DEFAULT_OPTS="--jobs 3 --with-bdeps=y --quiet --keep-going=y"
ENV_UNSET="DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY GOBIN PERL5LIB PERL5OPT PERLPREFIX PERL_CORE PERL_MB_OPT PERL_MM_OPT XAUTHORITY XDG_CACHE_HOME XDG_CONFIG_HOME XDG_DATA_HOME XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"
FCFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
FEATURES="assume-digests binpkg-docompress binpkg-dostrip binpkg-logs config-protect-if-modified distlocks ebuild-locks fixlafiles ipc-sandbox merge-sync multilib-strict network-sandbox news parallel-fetch pid-sandbox preserve-libs protect-owned sandbox sfperms strict unknown-features-warn unmerge-logs unmerge-orphans userfetch userpriv usersandbox usersync xattr"
FFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
GENTOO_MIRRORS="http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/gentoo"
LANG="C.UTF-8"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed"
MAKEOPTS=" -j4"
PKGDIR="/usr/portage/packages"
PORTAGE_CONFIGROOT="/"
PORTAGE_RSYNC_OPTS="--recursive --links --safe-links --perms --times --omit-dir-times --compress --force --whole-file --delete --stats --human-readable --timeout=180 --exclude=/distfiles --exclude=/local --exclude=/packages --exclude=/.git"
PORTAGE_TMPDIR="/var/tmp"
USE="acl amd64 berkdb bzip2 cli crypt cxx dri fortran gdbm iconv ipv6 libtirpc multilib ncurses nls nptl openmp pam pcre pulseaudio readline seccomp ssl tcpd unicode xattr zlib" ABI_X86="64" ALSA_CARDS="ali5451 als4000 atiixp atiixp-modem bt87x ca0106 cmipci emu10k1x ens1370 ens1371 es1938 es1968 fm801 hda-intel intel8x0 intel8x0m maestro3 trident usb-audio via82xx via82xx-modem ymfpci" APACHE2_MODULES="authn_core authz_core socache_shmcb unixd actions alias auth_basic authn_alias authn_anon authn_dbm authn_default authn_file authz_dbm authz_default authz_groupfile authz_host authz_owner authz_user autoindex cache cgi cgid dav dav_fs dav_lock deflate dir disk_cache env expires ext_filter file_cache filter headers include info log_config logio mem_cache mime mime_magic negotiation rewrite setenvif speling status unique_id userdir usertrack vhost_alias" CALLIGRA_FEATURES="karbon sheets words" COLLECTD_PLUGINS="df interface irq load memory rrdtool swap syslog" CPU_FLAGS_X86="mmx mmxext sse sse2" ELIBC="glibc" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="ashtech aivdm earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpsclock isync itrax mtk3301 nmea ntrip navcom oceanserver oldstyle oncore rtcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf skytraq superstar2 timing tsip tripmate tnt ublox ubx" GRUB_PLATFORMS="efi-64" INPUT_DEVICES="libinput keyboard mouse" KERNEL="linux" LCD_DEVICES="bayrad cfontz cfontz633 glk hd44780 lb216 lcdm001 mtxorb ncurses text" LIBREOFFICE_EXTENSIONS="presenter-console presenter-minimizer" NETBEANS_MODULES="apisupport cnd groovy gsf harness ide identity j2ee java mobility nb php profiler soa visualweb webcommon websvccommon xml" OFFICE_IMPLEMENTATION="libreoffice" PHP_TARGETS="php5-6 php7-1" POSTGRES_TARGETS="postgres9_5 postgres10" PYTHON_SINGLE_TARGET="python3_6" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_6" RUBY_TARGETS="ruby24" USERLAND="GNU" VIDEO_CARDS="amdgpu fbdev intel nouveau radeon radeonsi vesa dummy v4l" XTABLES_ADDONS="quota2 psd pknock lscan length2 ipv4options ipset ipp2p iface geoip fuzzy condition tee tarpit sysrq steal rawnat logmark ipmark dhcpmac delude chaos account"
Unset:  CC, CPPFLAGS, CTARGET, CXX, INSTALL_MASK, LC_ALL, LINGUAS, PORTAGE_BINHOST, PORTAGE_BUNZIP2_COMMAND, PORTAGE_COMPRESS, PORTAGE_COMPRESS_FLAGS, PORTAGE_RSYNC_EXTRA_OPTS
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome.  You say that `meson` fails, but you don't say in what way.  Without that information, it'll be nearly impossible for us to provide any help.

Comment: +Andy Dalton, I think I fixed it, is it correct now?

Comment: Note that it points you to the complete build log.  Do you see anything there?  You might consider asking your question on forums.gentoo.org as they'll be more Gentoo-centric people there.